# Explanation why empty scenekit scene without ship has one node and 2.73K polygons

Tags: statistics, scenekit, polygon

Why does an empty scenekit scene with the ship removed have one node and a 2.73K polygon count? If I expand the statistics view, there are two nodes and 5.46K polygons. It has to do something with the statistics view, but why so many polygons? And why is this view inside the scene?

Answer (score -1):

An empty SceneKit scene has always at least one node, because the node is the root node. It is the node to which you can add your other nodes as child nodes.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't explain the high polygon count.